# Android NDK: Including boost c++ library

Tags: android, boost, android-ndk, makefile

I am trying to use a boost library inside my android application, using the NDK. I have found a couple of success stories [here](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/comment-page-1/#comment-336) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882714/port-boost-to-android/4883976#4883976), but I can't say the same about me. I am specifically trying to use the library in [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/roots2.html), as well as the boost thread library. In the code below, I am only trying to include the thread library, not the math library. The process I used to build the boost libraries is pretty much the same as the first link I attached.

So far, it seems I have successfully built the boost libraries, but when I run `ndk-build`, I get the following error:

```
Prebuilt       : libboost_thread.a <= <NDK>/sources/
cp: omitting directory `path/to/ndk/sources/boost'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libboost_thread.a] Error 1
```

Obviously the `cp: omitting directory...` is not exactly an error. But the only thing I'm getting other than that is the next line, which doesn't really mean anything. `Error 1`

Here's my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := boost_thread
LOCAL_LDLIBS := lboost_system-gcc-md lboost_thread-gcc-md -lgnustl_static
LOCAL_LDLIBS += lboost_system-gcc-md lboost_thread-gcc-md \
         -L$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi \
         -lgnustl_static  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := #cpp_sources
LOCAL_MODULE := com_example_ndkFile_CppMethods
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,boost)
```

And there's also an Android.mk file in `path/to/ndk/sources/boost/`:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE:= boost_thread
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= android/lib/libboost_thread.a  
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)  
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

And my humble Application.mk file:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS = -fexceptions
```

I built the boost libraries using `bjam`. All of the `libboost_###.a` files are in the `sources/boost/android/lib` folder.

What is the error I'm getting?

Comment: Almost all information regarding installation, compilation is covered here
[Official “Boost library” Support for Android and iOS? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036311/official-boost-library-support-for-android-and-ios)

Answer (score 14):

I built the boost libraries using [Boost-for-Android](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android). Then I have in my boost/include/lib directory the android makefile boost.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# boost_date_time
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := boost_date_time
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_53.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# boost_filesystem
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := boost_filesystem
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# boost_thread
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := boost_thread
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_53.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# boost_system
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := boost_system
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# boost_program_options
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := boost_program_options
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libboost_program_options-gcc-mt-1_53.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# boost_chrono
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := boost_chrono
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libboost_chrono-gcc-mt-1_53.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and my module where i use some of the boost libraries looks like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# SignalServer, executable 
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS           := -DTIXML_USE_TICPP
#LOCAL_CFLAGS           += -DDEBUG
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := boost_thread \
    boost_system \
    boost_filesystem \
    boost_program_options \
    boost_chrono \
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ticpp \
    tia \
    tobicore \
    tobiid \
    tid \
    gdf
LOCAL_MODULE           := signalserver
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES       := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES       += $(LOCAL_PATH)/extern/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES       += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../boost/include/boost-1_53
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := #cpp source

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

in addition I have an Android.mk where all subdir makefiles are listed

```
TOP_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(TOP_PATH)/boost/lib/boost.mk
include $(TOP_PATH)/signalserver/signalserver.mk
.
.
```

and my Application.mk:

```
APP_PLATFORM          := android-14
APP_ABI               := armeabi-v7a
#APP_OPTIM             := debug
#NDK_DEBUG             := 1

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.6
APP_STL               := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS          := -fexceptions -frtti
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it fails (Missing LOCAL_MODULE before including BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY in jni/Android.mk). I am using also boost 1_53).

Answer (score 5):

Here: http://silverglint.com/boost-for-android/ you can find a simple script that lets you build a modern version of boost for android, or simply download prebuilt boost binaries.

Also included is a sample test app that shows you how to include/link the boost headers/binaries